# Process date that may be in one of two formats

Tags: php, oracle10g

I have a PHP application that uses the HTML5 `input type="date"`:

```
<input type="date" name="document_dt" id="document_dt" min="1899-12-30" max="2014-11-21" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="" maxlength="10" class="date">
```

When the system is accessed via modern browsers, this input element yields a date in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Older browsers don't suport HTML5 and treat that date field like a regular input box. In such cases, for legacy reasons well-outside of my control, the expected format is `DD-MON-YYYY` (ie: '28-FEB-2014').

How can I use either Oracle or PHP to consolidate these formats into 'YYYY-MM-DD', such that this snippet will work: `TO_DATE(document_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions.

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('28-FEB-2014'));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-05-28'));
var_dump($date1, $date2);

string(10) "2014-02-28"
string(10) "2014-05-28"
```

Comment: So PHP's strtotime() function performs some introspection on the incoming string?

Comment: [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) does, `date` just allows you to format it how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to check the format and then `\DateTime::createFromFormat` to do the conversion depending on which string you have.

```
$date = false;
$dateString = '28-FEB-2014';

if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i', $dateString)) {
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', $dateString);
} elseif (preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/', $dateString)) {
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateString);
}

if ($date) {
    // do something with date
} else {
    // invalid date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant piece of the solution I worked up in Oracle:

```
    IF document_dt IS NOT NULL THEN
        BEGIN
            v_document_dt:=TO_DATE(document_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                v_document_dt:=TO_DATE(document_dt, 'dd-mon-yyyy');
        END;
    ELSE
        v_document_dt:=SYSDATE;
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

If two formats i.e. patterns are known ones - its good. Just use PHP to determine which date format is it and parse it to needed one like this:

```
<?php
function process_date($date)
{
  if (preg_match('/^((0[1-9]|[12][012345678]|19)-(0[1-9]|1[012])|29-(0[13-9]|1[012])|30-(0[13-9]|1[012])|31-(0[13578]|1[02]))-(19|20)\d\d|29-02-(19|20)([02468][048]|[13579][26])$/', $date) === 1)
  {
    $d = explode("-", $date);
    $date = $d[2]."-".$d[1]."-".$d[0];
  }
  return $date;
}

echo process_date("2011-12-13")."<br>";
echo process_date("28-11-2014");
?>
```